Open a text file and use contents in OPENXML
I have a 50-line XML document saved in a text file. I would like to open that file and feed the contents into OPENXML. Am I missing some simple solution to this?
Reading threads here on SO and the dox on MS, the simplest solution I have found so far is:
DECLARE @file varchar(MAX) = 'mytest.xml'
DECLARE @xml varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @doc INT
SET @xml = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'my path', SINGLE BLOB) as DATA
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc OUTPUT, @xml
... and finally I can OPENXML

And I can't even use @file in the OPENROWSET because it complains it has to be a string, not a varchar!
Is there any way to simplify this?

it complains it has to be a string, not a varchar! there's no string type in SQL, it's either nvarchar or varchar. And unless you're absolutely certain the XML file is ASCII, you won't want varchar

OPENROWSET and friends likes constant strings and dislikes variables, so no, there's no easy way. You can write a procedure  that does this stuff to simplify things. Btw, OPENXML? Unless you know what you're doing, it hasn't been needed in like 15 years, .nodes and .query is the new hotness

@PanagiotisKanavos - exactly - you can't use a variable in this statement, you HAVE to use an actual string constant. So if you want to do something as simple as have a variable pointing to one of several files, you have to use DynamicSQL. It's baffling!

@siggemannen - it appears I have been reading all the wrong references (then again, the DB handed to be was V12...). I'll start on that bit now.

No, it's not baffling. You're using the wrong tool for the job. Databases are built to query the data in their tables, not files. Data virtualization services do exist, which allow treating files as tables, but these are for big data files stored on Spark servers or clusters

@siggemannen - ahhh, the bit I didn't mention is that this is for a JOIN to do many UPDATEs, and .nodes is apparently orders of mag slower for this.

Worse and worse. Import the data into a table and use the table. To get good speed add the appropriate indexes. You can't add indexes to files.

Well, it's faster (although i wouldn't say magnitudes) but clunker, easy to leak and uses more memory . Unless you're parsing +50mb files, nodes etc is fine

@PanagiotisKanavos - baffling that they don't let you use a variable for the file name.

@MauryMarkowitz, did you have a chance to try the proposed solution?

@YitzhakKhabinsky = not yet, I'm strongly moving towards JSON instead for simplicity sake.

Please try the following conceptual solution.
Notable points:

It is using a T-SQL variable pointing to an XML file on the file
system.
It is very fast.

Microsoft proprietary OPENXML() and its companions sp_xml_preparedocument and sp_xml_removedocument are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, OPENXML() cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.
books.xml
<books>
  <book id="1">
    <title>Book A</title>
    <author>Jack Welch</author>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <title>Book B</title>
    <author>Henry Ford</author>
  </book>
</books>

SQL
/*
Step #1: Load XML file into single row db table
*/
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (XMLColumn XML);
DECLARE @Filepath VARCHAR(100) = 'e:\Temp\books.xml';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT BulkColumn 
   FROM Openrowset(Bulk N' + QUOTENAME(@Filepath, NCHAR(39)) + ', Single_Blob) x;';

PRINT @sql;

INSERT INTO @tbl (XMLColumn)
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

-- just to see
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

/*
Step #2: Shred XML without dynamic SQL
*/
--INSERT INTO <TARGET TABLE>   -- uncomment when you are ready
SELECT c.value('@id', 'INT') AS id
   , c.value('(title/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') As title
   , c.value('(author/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') As author
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY XMLColumn.nodes('/books/book') AS t(c);

